# Cutting a shape out of an object with another object

Tags: modeling, mesh, objects

I'm trying to recreate these F holes in the body without cutting into the bodies mesh[image]

The F holes and body are two separate meshes.
[image]

I am completely lost as to how to cut out a hole in my main body mesh without messing it up.

Is there any way to use the F hole mesh to make a hole in the body mesh?[image]

[http://imgur.com/a/rDoVR](https://imgur.com/a/rDoVR)

Comment: You can use the Knife Project tool as described in the answer [here](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-do-you-draw-a-circle-onto-another-object).

Comment: You could also use a [boolean modifier](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans).

Answer (score 3):

You can use knife project.
(from the wiki)
Knife projection is a non-interactive tool where you can use objects to cookie-cut into the mesh rather than hand drawing the line.

This works by using the outlines of other selected objects in edit-mode to cut into the mesh, resulting geometry inside the cutters outline will be selected.

Outlines can be wire or boundary edges.

To use Knife Project, in 'object' mode select the "cutting object" first then shift select the "object to be cut". Now tab into edit mode and press "knife project".
[image]