# How do I gently bend 4 bottle sides inward simultaneously to create a uniform dent?

Tags: modeling

Trying to create a dent on 4 sides simultaneously on a roundish square bottle. But first in order to get it symetrical I should find away to select the same face area on each 4 sides.  Ideas? Suggestions?

[image]

Comment: I'm surprised no one has suggested proportional editing yet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using high dense objects in this kind of modeling is wrong.

> Low density topology is more easy to manipulate

I would suggest using subsurface modeling.

---

- **Add a cube and subdivid it one time and scale the middle loop inward a bit.**
- **Add a subsurface modifier.**

[image: Cube]

- **Now extrude couple of time to get the shape of the mouth of the bottle.**
- **Use the circle operation from the loops tools to get a perfect circle at the top.**

[image: Cube 2]

- **Add a bevel modifier and set it to weight,mark the lower loop with edge bevel weight,This will make the lower loop a sharp one.**

[image: Cube 3]

- **To add the indentation we will select every side and insert a face using the insert tool with the ratio 0.5 and then by using the circle tool,convert it to a circle and then scale it with the factor 0.8 in its axis.(make sure the new edges don't have bevel weight).**

[image: Cube 4]

- **Select all the new faces and then extrude them inward and mark the exterior and the interior edges with bevel weight.**

[image: Cube 5]

- **and by this you have your bottle.with a clean and nice topology,you can do some more edits to math your references.**

[image: Cybe 6]

Answer (score 3):

May I suggest a Lattice?

[image: moving mouse cursor in scale mode, showing how the lattice middle vertices moved closer to center affect the mesh]

Create a Lattice object, and link it to the bottle with a Lattice modifier on the bottle object. Set the Lattice object to an acceptable resolution, and in Edit mode, move some lattice vertices closer to the center with the Scale transform tool. The deformation depends on the subdivision of the lattice and the selection of vertices. Experiment until you find the correct values for your situation.

[image: an example of higher lattice subdivision leaving stronger corners in the mesh]

Comment: Seems by the Lattice modifier animated example above I won't get the square-ish effect, rather rounds the whole thing(?)

Comment: @Marc More subdivisions on the lattice should help with that.

Comment: This is not a reliable modeling technique.

Answer (score 2):

What may be the easiest is to just use a *Boolean modifier> difference*. While in top orthographic view, you can place your *difference* objects where you need them, perhaps start with a uv sphere. After placing the first uv sphere, press  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>, then move the duplicate across on the x or y axis and repeat until you have your four target objects.

To make placement simpler, select your press  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>S</kbd>*>cursor to center*, then  <kbd>Shift</kbd> +<kbd>S</kbd> *selection to cursor* after selecting your object while in *object mode*. Add a uv sphere, and press <kbd>G</kbd> then <kbd>X</kbd> or <kbd>Y</kbd> and move the object accordingly. Repeat for the three remaining spheres.

Add your *Boolean modifier>difference* to your bottle object, with 'sphere' as the target object. Then add another *Boolean>difference* with "sphere.001" as the target, and so on. Then apply the Booleans in the order added, and you should be all set.

Answer (score 1):

You could cut the bottle into fourths and then add a mirror on both the Y and X axis. From there you can easily indent the bottle by simply moving a vertex with a connected constraint to it.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE MadDog!  Please try to add some more details, like maybe a screenshot or [GIF](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/963/what-is-the-process-for-creating-gifs-for-questions-and-answers) of how this is done.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For future models you should remember to place objects in the center, wich makes symetrical and precise editing a lot easier.
Doing that later can be a bit tricky.
For doing the circle i would suggest not to select square faces like you, but rather adding a circle from the add-menu, rotating it 90 degrees along the x-axis, aligning it along the z-axis and pulling it towards you, so it is in front of the mesh. then you would want to use a knife project:
[Cutting a shape out of an object with another object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/8894/cutting-a-shape-out-of-an-object-with-another-object)
get the circle behind the bottle (move along y-axis) and change the view with numpad 4 or 6 to the back and do the same.
repeat that for the sides.
when you're done with that you can select the circles with shift+alt+right mouse button in vertex mode and scale them to your needs (if you select front and back circle/ left and right you can scale them along just one axis to move them in.
it's actually pretty simple.

Comment: there might be faster ways. you could use the cut through option to save a few keystrokes. + for precise editing you can always set values for moving, extruding and scaling via your number keys. (for extruding for example you press e, x/y/z and then something like 0.2 to extrude the mesh 0.2 blender units along the desired axis)

Comment: Wow, thanks. Sounds like it would work. But unfortunately that's way beyond my current modeling abilities. I'll just mess with selecting each side one by one and using "O" in edit to dent each side.

Comment: i'll see if i have some spare time in the next days and depending on that i'll upload and link a video explaining it, so a beginner can understand and follow the steps (it's really simple, trust me. these things come with time, experimenting and practice. then you'll be able to figure out the most things on your own)

Comment: I'm grateful. Thank you. But just as I attempt to work thru it on my own now anyways... It seems like what you're describing is like a boolean operation whereas I'm sectioning one object from another.. so with that in mind don't you mean add a sphere? Not a circle? A circle is flat so cutting something flat from this does not seem like it will make a dent. If that makes any sense a'tal.

Comment: nah, i don't mean boolean. a circle, not a sphere, because it's not about erasing something of the bottle, but rather "burning" the shape of the circle into the bottle and then moving the faces inside of that "burned" circle inwards (: