# I can't find the Retopo menu

Tags: mesh

I am very new to blender but have made some good progress recently. I have a curved surface that I need to cut a precise hole in and from YouTube videos it seems that the Retopo method is the way to go. The problem I have is that I can't get to the menu where I can call upon it.

I am using a MS Surface Pro 3 with a Bluetooth keyboard. It doesn't have a dedicated F9 key but if I push the F key and the F9 multi key it should be the same thing.

Can anyone help?

Cheers
Chris

Comment: Which retopo tool? Grease pencil retopology?

Comment: The one described in this video Charles.

Comment: http://cgcookie.com/blender/2009/09/09/tip-cutting-a-hole-in-a-curved-surface/

Comment: Thanks Stacker I'll give it a try. Are any of you guys familiar with the Mesh Panel and how to get to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The video you mention is very old, it uses blender 2.49 which was before the major interface overhaul that started with blender 2.50. The mesh panel you are looking for had several things grouped together that are now in different places.

The retopology part that you are after is now better defined under [snapping options](https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/transform/transform_control/precision/snap.html). With transform snapping enabled set the snap element to face and you can have vertices you move snap to an existing surface.

Blendercookie has a more recent [retopology video](https://cgcookie.com/archive/tip-stone-retopology-methods/) that you should find helpful.

Comment: Thank you very much sambler. You have been a great help!

Comment: @ArnoldBennett If this answer has satisfactorily answered your question, consider marking it as accepted by clicking the checkmark.

Comment: The link seems dead as of 2016-07

Comment: @fabriced I updated the snapping options link to the new blender manual site. I'm not certain which cgcookie tutorial that was but the stone retopology tutorial that is now in the archives seems to be from the right time. - it is also on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KEZhyIuh-Sk)

Answer (score 1):

To cut holes in other objects can choose between the [*Boolean Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Booleans) and [*Knife Project*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Meshes/Editing/Subdividing/Knife_Subdivide)

Select the surface and a circle in object mode.
In *Edit Mode* select *Top-View* <kbd>7</kbd>
And click *Knife Project* from the Tools-Panel* or Space and enter knife.

[image]
[image]

Unselect the contour of the circle with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>RMB</kbd>

[image]

Delete the selected vertices <kbd>X</kbd>:

[image]

In case your curved surface is currently no mesh you could convert it from curves to mesh <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>C</kbd>.

Related:

- [How would you cut a shape out of an object using another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object/7933#7933)