# How would I cut across a plane using a die-like mesh/curve?

Tags: modifiers, objects, bezier-curves

I'm in the process of creating a visual model of a product made using 2D CAD software. The .svg which I have imported into blender is the file sent to a laser cutter which would out cut across an acrylic sheet wherever there is a path in order to form the shape.

I was wondering if there is a way of cutting the plane such that the result would be similar to what would be carried out by the laser cutter (imagine the resultant shape being cut out of plane using a knife with runs along the path, if that makes sense)

I've tried to use the Boolean modifier to achieve the effect I am looking for but with limited success. It only seems to cut out a small section of the design for reasons which I do not understand:

[image: Curve without any modifications] [image: Plane with the Boolean modification applied with operation: difference which is the closest setting to what I want]

Comment: Did you try to do that with Knife Project?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? Why do you want to cut that shape into a plane? Do you want a solid shape with the same contours as your curve object?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To cut the shape on the plane with a curve object you can use **Knife Project** tool. Place your curve object above the plane, while its selected hold <kbd>Shift</kbd> and select the plane, switch to **Top View**, then **Orthogonal View** by hitting <kbd>5</kbd> on the *Numeric Keypad* and change to **Edit Mode**.

Then In **Edit Mode** select **Knife Project** in Tools tab.

To avoid errors in the mesh, before using Knife Project tool you can subdivide the plane few times or convert the curve object to mesh.

[image]