# Cut a plane with a curve

Tags: modeling

I know there's many question about cutting a mesh with another mesh but I need to ask this because the boolean modifier isn't working.

I need to cut the plane with the shape of the track (that is another plane with an array and curve modifier) and get the inversion of the track cut onto the plane.

How can I do it?

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This sounds like a job for *Knife Project Tool*. This answer should help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28532/

Comment: Thank you! this worked!