# How do I remove part of my object?

Tags: modeling, mesh

How to remove a part of the object grid which is not included object 7?

[image]

Comment: Very odd looking mesh . . . Select all that you want of the seven, then press `Ctrl`+`I` to invert the selection. Next you can press `Delete` to remove that partof the mesh

Comment: @user16030 ..are those two mesh or a  single one? if they are two, do you want to cut a hole in the plane with the "7" shape?

Comment: It's 2 meshes, i want cut in plane mesh that seven number.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you cut a shape out of an object using another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cut an object along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve)