# Pattern on Easter Egg for 3D-Printing

Tags: modeling, mesh, 3d-printing

I try to produce such handmade carved easter eggs: http://weburbanist.com/2010/05/22/insanely-intricate-eggshell-art-by-franc-grom/. I'm not able to sketch directly on the egg surface. I'm only beginner in 3D, so I have 2 questions:

1. How could I put and arrange such pattern on the surface?
2. How could I produce "holes/breakthroughs" in the object geometry for 3D-printing (using the 3D-printed pattern as template to transfer the pattern to the "real" egg surface using a pencil)?

Thanks for your help.

Regards,
Thomas

---

I unwrapped the mesh in "sphere projection". Then I applied this texture http://www.123rf.com/photo_35224838_vector-damask-seamless-pattern-background-elegant-luxury-texture-for-wallpapers-backgrounds-and-page.html two times onto the uv-map in an external image-processing-software. Then I applied this texture to the object in blender, which distorts the texture to the north and south pole. I don't know, how to align e.g. this pattern http://www.derwesten.de/img/incoming/origs7781524/6226267404-w552-h740-bF3F3F3-st/55449025-300x402.jpg or http://img.weburbanist.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/franc-grom-eggshell-art-1.jpg (no distortion to the poles).

My idea to produce the "breakthroughs" for 3D printing is to "bake" the pattern/texture onto an uv-map based on stripes or two circles. Then export this uv-map as image, import in vector-processing-software (e.g. Inkscape) and create bezier curves/paths and export this vector format. Then import the vector format in blender and bend the curves/paths along the given egg-shape-path, that a new egg object is created. Then delete the "breakthroughs" or apply this new object to the given egg object using boolean.

Question to the blender experts: How to bend the imported curves/paths along a path and apply the boolean? I hope, that someone could give me an example.

Comment: UV map projection could be set to cylinder or sphere with pretty good effect

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. It's better just to keep 1 question per post to get the best, most specific answers. You can ask as many questions as you need as separate posts.

Comment: This is generally not a very trivial thing to do. You could try using grease pencil strokes to draw over your surface and then convert them to bezier curves, bevel them and use Booleans to intersect with your egg object, or you could draw 2d shapes and use Knife project to cut wholes in your egg as described here http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560

Answer (score 2):

What I did was use a bezier circle to curve the shape I used to cut into my sphere. A simple *curve deform* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> after selecting my imported .svg, then the circle.

As for the pattern cut into the sphere:

I first removed doubles on the imported curve after converting it to a mesh object with <kbd>W</kbd>*>remove doubles* and then used limited dissolve to clean it up a little more and recalculated normals with  <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>. Finally extruding the object to give it the thickness I wanted.

The last step for the cut itself, was joining the sphere and pattern objects as one, then going to *edit mode*, and selecting only the imported object and placing it where needed. Then finally, via the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu, searched for *Boolean*, and the hole was cut.

Here's a little .gif showing that part of the process. [image]

*Edit in response to comment*:

This will only address the first of the images and should get you in the direction of the desired result.

1. Add a UV sphere, in the *operator panel*, increase rings and segments as desired. I used 120 segments, and 60 rings. Scale along the Z axis to the appropriate shape.
2. Apply a *decimate modifier* set to *unsubdivide* with one iteration.
   [image]
3. In *edit mode* select all face loops that will be **kept**.

[image]

4. Invert selection with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>I</kbd> and then press <kbd>X</kbd> and delete the selected faces.

[image]

5. Select the face loops that should be raised with <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>RMB</kbd> and then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>>*Region(vertex normals)*

[image]

6. <kbd>Tab</kbd> back into *object mode*, add a *solidify modifier*, adjust to the desired thickness. Add *subsurf* if desired.

[image]

Using these steps you can go in a few directions and should be able to get the results you're after.

Comment: Could you give me an example to get this result: http://www.derwesten.de/img/incoming/origs7781524/6226267404-w552-h740-bF3F3F3-st/55449025-300x402.jpg or http://img.weburbanist.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/franc-grom-eggshell-art-1.jpg

Comment: @ThomasSchmiedl see my edit.

Comment: Thanks Timaroberts for your patience. Please, could you give me a workflow for my idea to get such results: http://img.weburbanist.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/05/franc-grom-eggshell-art-1.jpg. Bending the imported bezier curves/paths (vector format) 2-times and joining the vertices to get a new egg object? Or does this not work.