# Form a circular Mesh out of an object

Tags: mesh

Complete beginner here just three days experience.

I am creating a bottle water, picture below. and I want to achieve two things.

1. I want to have a circular mesh in the shape of the circle beside the bottle to cut all the 3 bottom swimming lines like as if it is part of the bottle on both sides.
2. I also have a vector logo which will go into the circle all meshed together with the bottle.

Like I said I am a complete beginner, and I will be glad if someone can point a very easy and straightforward tutorial to achieve this.

Thanks

**Edit**

Look at this plastic.

[image]

I want to achieve the annotated bump on the plastic below where the annotation is using the circular shape beside the plastic or any means possible.

[image]

Guide will be appreciated

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to cut an object along a curve?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve)

Comment: I think the aim is to add a label on the bottle. Is that it?

Comment: No, please refer to edit

Comment: As @DuarteFarrajotaRamos said a possibility is to cut (but only the front part: there is an option for that), and once cut, model the interior. You can also try sculpting or editing with proportional edit mode.

Comment: Hi @lemon, DuateFarrajotaRamos duplicate suggestion did the trick. However, there were jaggy contours and the bottle face isn't smooth anymore, any suggestion. Perhaps you explain the 'sculpting or editing with proportional edit mode'

Comment: Hi Temitayo. The result and the way to do it, in any case, will depend on how is the bottle's mesh topology. Could you upload it or add a picture with the wireframe visible? A link to upload to BSE: http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @lemon here you go http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2905/
Nice name by the way

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some tips concerning the circular cut, starting from the [answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve) indicated by [Duarte Farrajota Ramos](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/19307/duarte-farrajota-ramos) in the comments.

The result is the following, and this answer is concerning the cut only and its cleanup, not the logo part (as the approach may be very depending on the logo shape itself):

[image]

Just to say, we can notice that the starting mesh is very clean and uses a subdivision modifier so that we have a reasonable amount of vertices to work on:

[image]

After the cut is done, we obtain some distortions, as the cutting circle geometry does not correspond to the bottle. This is particularly visible without the subsurface modifier:

[image]

So, the cleanup consists mainly on three actions (and this works because we know that we'll have the subdivision modifier after that):

- Dissolving unwanted vertices
- Merging vertices
- Adjust cut position

Dissolving vertices:

- Select them
- Use <kbd>X</kbd> and choose 'dissolve vertices'
- The aim is to do that 'everywhere' to make quads again around the hole (again, we know that subdivision surface modifier will compensate that)

[image]

Mergin vertices:

At some places this is easier to merge <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>, either at center or at the last selected.

[image]

Adjust cut position:

Select the wanted vertex and use <kbd>G</kbd> *twice* to move it along the edge:

[image]

Once all done, in this case, remove the inner part of the cut:

[image]

Now select the border, extrude <kbd>E</kbd>, and scale <kbd>S</kbd> a bit. The aim for that is to isolate the central part with a 'clean' edge loop:

[image]

Last steps, filling the hole:

[image]

Continue that as possible and finally adjust vertices in the same way as the beginning so that almost all faces are quads:

[image]

[Link to the blend file](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2907/)

Comment: Thanks, but there is a problem, how do I get you a bottle of wine? :) . Thanks so much