# Creating curve design

Tags: bezier-curves

[image]

Hi, in the image below you can see point "3" is the bottle that I created using blender 2.69. "1" is the side view of the original bottle "2" is the front view of the bottle. Now I want this design of the curve on my blender bottle, but I have no guess how to achieve it. I mean how to create those design on the bottle. The curves on bottle are like small gutter which are towards inside of the bottle.

Comment: Are the knife tool (K shortcut) and bevel (Ctrl B shortcut) available in edit mode in 2.69?

Comment: Yes these options are available, but how can these create curves?

Comment: Related also: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/75187/form-a-circular-mesh-out-of-an-object/75255#75255

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some technics to do that (I won't make here the exact same bottle...):

*Knife cut*

The cut is straight, but the result is parabolic due to the bottle shape.

[image]

*Knife project*

Again a curved shape obtained from a flat curve.

- Create a cutting shape (here a plane)
- Scale/orientate it
- Shift select the bottle and enter edit mode in the bottle (both are selected and that indicates to Blender which shape(s) will cut the bottle)
- Use 'knife project'
- In your situation, make sure that 'cut through' is checked

[image]

*Beveling*

- In edge selection mode
- Select the wanted edge loops
- Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>
- Choose bevel depth with <kbd>Numpad +</kbd> and <kbd>Numpad -</kbd>

Once done, give a shape, for instance selecting the two face loops as below and scale them:

[image]

*Draw it flat and bend the shape*

- Use a mirror to make so the future cutting lines will match
- Add a simple deform modifier to bend the shape to 360°
- Make the cuts/bevels as previously
- Apply the modifiers and remove doubles when the shape is as you want
- Add a subsurface modifier
- Scale and merge (or extrude and model) the shape to fit your bottle

[image]

Comment: I will try the solution provided by you and then will reach to you master ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Supplementing the options provided by lemon, here is a different approach. Before any other steps, instead of having the vertical edges parallel to the z axis, twist the bottle so that the edges now vertical become helical around the z axis. Adding the groves around the bottle might then be able to be achieved by standard methods of adding geometry.

Comment: I agree. This is to add to the toolbox!