# Cutting shape out of extruded subdivided plane

Tags: topology

[image: subdivided and extruded plane]

I have a subdivided and extruded plane.  I wish to cut a shape *out of it* with a cyclic (closed) bezier curve so I can use this topography to do proportional editing on it.  I have found lots of ways to make holes in the plane but no good way to cleanly just cut out the shape leaving this topography in that shape. I have been going nuts over this for a week or so.  Maybe I'm just missing something. Help.

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve

Comment: Duarte Farrajota Ramos:The problem with the methods shown in the above link is the same as I have been trying.  Problem is I need the cutout to retain the topography of the plane I am cutting out from.  That is done if a how is cut in the plane however I can not get that from the shape removed.

Comment: Do you mean you want to keep all the existing vertices and their topology, just move them aside to make a hole in the desired shape?