# Is there a way to bisect using a compound line or curve?

Tags: knife-tool, bisect

Right now, the bisect tool only works with a single straight line. I'm just wondering if the the question above is possible and, if so, how?

Comment: Hello :). It is indeed possible. Is this thread what you had in mind? https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50538/78972