# Add bezier curve to vertices along a plane?

Tags: bezier-curves, vertices, edges

Newbie to Blender here.

I'm wondering how to get some knife-cut edges to follow a more precise path along the black doorway section of an "image-to-plane" piece I have here.

Is it possible to add a bezier curve to an edge in edit mode? If not, what workarounds would you recommend I try to trace around this door?
Thank you!

[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can apply a bezier curve to a plane using the knife project tool.

Heres my process:

As a separate object, make the curve that you want (mine is pretty bad for a door):
[image: curve]

Next, covert the curve to a mesh using the "convert to" tool:

[image: converting]

Now, select first the curve mesh, and then the plane, go into edit mode, and do knife project:

[image: project]

The knife project does it from your view, so you want to use align view to make sure you are looking at the plane head-on.

Now, you will have the curve cut into your plane:

[image: final]

Comment: This worked like a charm! Thank you for your help!!