# How to make a curve on the face of a plane

Tags: objects

I am new in blender and I watched some tutorials on this issue but I did not find any solution.

**I want a little curve on a single side of a plane**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A solution with Blender 2.82.

In ***Object Mode*** , add a bezier curve then pass on ***Edit Mode***.

You can draw a new curve by clicking on icon ***Draw***.

You can draw on a mesh if you select on ***Tool*** tab , the *Method of projecting depth* : ***Surface***.
[image]

Comment: I did it as per you said but didn't work.have a look on screenshot and please help me getting out from it.Thanks  https://ibb.co/GR5ryKv

Comment: So I'm not sure what you want to do. Perhaps do you want to project or to draw a curve to a plane ?

Comment: i just want to make a straight side of plane in to curve.

Comment: Try with this method : https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/170132/add-bezier-curve-to-vertices-along-a-plane/170134#170134