# Depth based on arbitrary shape

Tags: modeling

Please tell me, I have a figure of 5 curves that are interconnected. How can I draw a given figure on a cube and make a recess in the cube based on this figure.
This form you need to make a recess in the cube.[image]

Comment: Hi, welcome. It is not much easy to understand your setup, if you could perhaps add a relevant image to your post, editing the question and using the image upload tool, that would greatly help others to understand and maybe help you

Comment: @m.ardito updated, please see.

Comment: Hi :). This answer could help: https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/50538/