# How to save the knife tool cut line?

Tags: knife-tool

How can I save the line before cutting <kbd>↲ Enter</kbd>? I thought of vertex groups, though can't use them for this purpose since the line disappears immediately on clicking outside the mesh.

Comment: Why not draw a bezier curve instead and use it as knife project? https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560

Comment: That's the answer @DuarteFarrajotaRamos