# Is it possible to have the Knife tool cut non-straight lines?

Tags: modeling, knife-tool

Beginner user of Blender here. Would it be possible to have the Knife Tool draw unstraight lines similar to the Annotation Tool..? Basically, what I want to do is to try and cut out a part of an object and leave the edges smooth but the Knife always cuts in straight lines.
(apologies for the poor wording)

Comment: Hi :). No that's not possible, Knife tool only cuts straight edges. You can use *Knife project* with a curve to get a more 'smooth' result.

Comment: @JachymMichal: well, if use the knife tool, zoom in a lot and click a lot - you can do non-straight lines :D

Comment: @Chris true dat :D

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560

Comment: Alright thanks for the suggestions