# How to cut a mesh with a plane?

Tags: modeling

I'm trying to cut the mesh in grey with the plane in yellow to get a rounded face. I tried with the Bolean Modifier but no way it doesn't work.  I'm using the version 2.7. [image]Thanks for your help.

Comment: Cutting that shape with Boolean will work after you extrude the plane thus making it manifold. Other than that to cut with this plane use *Knife Project*. Related - http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object

Comment: Thanks Mr Zak. I tried it, extruding the vertical plane but nothing happens as I use Bolean Modifier. Maybe thsi si because the grey mesh has both opposite faces open?

Comment: Somehow related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve

Comment: Yes, the object to be cut shouldn't have any holes too (although it can work depending on the case), so both objects should be manifold.