# Cutting *only* existing geometry with a circle

Tags: modeling, vertices, edges, geometry

Is it possible to cut *only the existing geometry of an object* using a particular shape (for instance the circle in red) to add vertices ***only where the shape bisects an existing edge?***

[image: Here]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How would you cut a shape out of an object using another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object)

Comment: Nope, i saw that, its adding lot of poly i dont need, i dont want to get circular area with as much edges original circle had, i want to just add cuts where my circle is overlaping existing geometry as in my picture ... straight cuts.

Comment: Try subdividing each edge as 1 time per vertex (*W > Subdivide*), aligning the vertices with your demo circle, and using the *Knife tool* (*K*) to connect them and cut the in between faces.

Comment: Thx for answer but this is just simple example, would be possible some more "automated" aproach? Imagine i dont want to cut 8 polygons but 800, this process would kill me :)

Comment: Because i dont know the orange mesh, i want to create it based on that circle, this is whole point of this question :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I will assume that you know how to use the *Knife Project* tool but if not, there are plenty of tutorials on BSE that can show you.

Here's a simple technique that might help you achieve what you're after:

Get everything ready to use the ***Knife Project*** tool but just before you do, select ***all*** of the vertices of the shape you want cut, and add them to a ***Vertex Group***.  Once you do that, cut your shape out with the ***Knife Project*** tool.  You can then ***Deselect*** the vertices from your original Vertex Group and use the ***Dissolve Vertices*** feature to get rid of the unwanted vertices that you added with ***Knife Project***:

[image]

Comment: Looks promissing and working, thx a lot. Marked as solution.