# How do you delete part of an intersected mesh from a certain direction?

Tags: modeling, modifiers, edit-mode

When there're 2 objects intersected like this:

[image: Mesh]

If I wanted to remove only the part above the green line, how would I do it? the Boolean Modifier doesn't seem to have anything to be used in cases like this.

Better view of both objects:

[image: View]

Comment: I'm not sure to get it, but if boolean doesn't help, you could try "knife project" tool, eg: see https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object/

Comment: @m.ardito turned out a mess, probably because they're intersected and the orange object passes through the yellow one completely.

Comment: By any chance, is it possible to separate the orange object into two different objects using the yellow object as delimiter? or creating faces in between above and below, in a way that makes the part above a loose part that I can delete after separating manually?

Comment: I tried doing this with a cube: https://i.imgur.com/kllWczd.png but it was pointless, the result looks so bad it could be said to be randomized. Maybe I should deal with the loose parts first, I wish there was a way to simply convert a mesh with loose parts to a solid mesh, I'll need to use a hundred boolean modifiers on that wig.