# Why isn't limited dissolve working?

Tags: mesh, geometry

I was trying to google a way to merge overlapping meshes and everyone keeps saying Limited Dissolve, but it's not working for me for some reason :< ... I just want to make one n-gon without anything in the middle.
[image]

Comment: Why would they be dissolved? Only connected geometry located on the surface not exceeding specified angle will be dissolved. In your case circles don't seem to be connected. These are 3 intersecting but different meshes

Comment: But I joined them >.> ... How do I merge them and get rid of the extra vertices then? <.<

Comment: You have been misinformed, limited dissolve is not the tool you are looking for

Comment: Could you please suggest what might work?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object or https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The maybe easiest way in this situation is manual stitching:

Just select a single vert from the inside of the circles.

[image]

Then hit <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd>. That way you enter vertex slide mode. Move the vert towards the outside and put it where both circles intersect. That way you keep angles roughly consistent. The more you zoom in, the more precise it gets.

[image]

The rest is stitching stuff together with <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>M</kbd>. I usually prefer to use merge 'At Last'. Just put the rest of the verts on the newly placed verts.

[image]

You could extrude the circles into cylinders and use booleans but it's not worth the hassle, especially since they're already in a single mesh.

If you lose one of the faces, simply clear the selection, select all the verts that belong to it, for example with Circle Select <kbd>C</kbd> and then hit <kbd>F</kbd> to create the face.

If the holes are easy enough for Blender to understand, selecting everything and hitting <kbd>F</kbd>  will work, too.

https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/vertices.html

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I was trying to do it manually, but after removing the inner vertices and connecting everything back together, I just get the outline of edges and vertices, not a mesh sheet for some reason.
Edit: ok, dissolving them, rather than deleting, seems to have solved it, which is kinda strange since it didn't work on the WHOLE thing, just if i select the inside vertices.

Comment: Edit 2: nm, it looks like dissolve worked on just the vertices of one circle, like it's supposed to, but the circles don't appear to be connected since if i connect their respective vertices by "F", mesh disappears leaving just the outline...

Comment: @Raksha Added a bit. If you use ALT M, they become connected. Before you merge, no circle cares for any other.