# CAD Sketch Add On

Tags: add-on

I am quite new to Blender and loving it.

I come from a background in Fusion 360 so I am very used to being able the make a sketch on any surface and extrude and cut into complex shapes.

Are there any Add Ons that add a similar function?

Thanks

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560