# Make a Cut with diffrent Object

Tags: modeling, 3d-view

how can I make a oval Cut like the red Markin without deleting the faces which are inside the second object?

[image]

The Object should be a Submarine and I want a Window like this in the front.

[image]

Comment: Hello, it's a bit hard to understand, could you please elaborate or reformulate?

Comment: Could you define "second" object ? Do you plan to use boolean operations ? Do you want to use the knife tool and to constrain it along the intersection ?

Comment: Hi both of you thanks for the fast response. Let me rephrase.
The oval on the right side just defines the Form of the cut which I want to have on the left Object. 
TL:DR I want the left Object to have a oval cut in the front which I could scale and push to the front or inside. (hope that makes more sense)

Comment: May I suggest to read this post: [How to cut an object along a curve?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/50538/how-to-cut-an-object-along-a-curve/50560#50560) ?

Comment: Cut the original shape and separate as new object if needed?

Comment: Another related post: [How would you cut a shape out of an object using another object?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/7928/how-would-you-cut-a-shape-out-of-an-object-using-another-object).