# How do I cut a semicircle into a curved surface?

Tags: modeling, workflow

How can I cut a semi-circle out of a curved surface, such as this:

[image: this object on a rifle]

As you can see from the picture, the circled area is one I'm having trouble with. I can't seem to find a way to cut a hole into a curved surface without messing up the topology. Could someone help me with this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Cutting a circular hole in a hollow cylinder without distorting the cylinder](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder)

Comment: @Ray Mairlot, don't think its a duplicate, see the answers are quite different.

Comment: The problem with this question is its not matching the photo (which shows gaps in a cylinder).

Comment: @24Duckies - Can you edit your question so its not a duplicate of http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder ?

Comment: @ideasman42 yes, upon closer inspection of the picture I see the difference, was going by the title too much.

Answer (score 5):

*Cutting* it without messing up the topology (ngons, tris, unwanted distortions, etc.) will be hard.

However, for your specific case I think you might have better luck building the shape by extruding/filling.

For example:

1. Duplicate a cylinder:

   [image]
2. Select some of the edges along the top/bottom of the cylinder and press <kbd>W</kbd>*>Bridge edge loops*:

   [image]
3. Repeat for the other side(s), then add a solidify and a subserf modifier:

   [image]