# Why do I get weird shading around a hole created with Bool Tools?

Tags: modeling

I want to make a hole and used the Bool Tools - Difference operation

[image]

But kinda get some weird shading around the hole. Is there a way to get rid of this or there is a better method?

[image]

Comment: can you attach the file

Comment: possibly related to http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/cutting-holes-with-boolean-modifier-makes-subdivision-surface-impossible

Comment: I've explained it in [my answer here.](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/34451/how-to-cut-holes-in-an-object-using-another-object) See the part with the screen shots of the sphere.

Comment: Thank you @Mentalist :) Fixed with one of your tips in your previous post.

Comment: Glad it helped! :-)