# Cutting into cylinder

Tags: modifiers, topology

I was modeling a chess set. Bishop was my biggest problem. The slice looks ok without a subsurf. Add a subsurf of 2 and ugliness happens.
[image]
I went to just practicing on a cylinder. looks ok, but I'm still get creases/folds. I get the slice by beveling a flat cube and booleaning.

[image][image]

So far this is the best I can get.

Thanks for any help or suggestions. Just another noob wading neck deep in blender water.

Not sure if my solution is a perfect as I would like, but here is what I ended up with.[image]
[image]
I removed the edges inside the slice and allowed the Subsurf to create the curve. That eliminated the mega ngons that was being created.

Comment: Welcome to Blender.SE! Could you spend a few more words about what exactly are your modeling needs? To solve this issue you could for example 1) put boolean modifier on the bottom of the stack 2) find the right topology for the shape to work with a subsurf of level 2... which one? or a third way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cutting Holes with Boolean Modifier Makes Subdivision Surface Impossible](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/cutting-holes-with-boolean-modifier-makes-subdivision-surface-impossible)

Answer (score 2):

Here's one way I would approach it:

- Select the faces to create the indentation, and [Inset](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/modeling/meshes/editing/duplicating/inset.html#inset-faces) with *tweak* enabled. <kbd>I</kbd> while holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>
  . (If desired,
  you may change you [transform orientaion](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/editors/3dview/object/editing/transform/control/orientations.html#transform-orientations) to *normal*,
  and rotate the faces to suit your object better.)
- Crease the edges that border the hole with
  <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>
- Bevel the creased edges with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>

[image]

Final result:

[image]