# Applying Boolean Breaks Topology

Tags: modifiers

I'm trying to apply what I think is a fairly simple bool operation but I can't figure out what the problem is or what to do to remedy the situation.

When modling with the modifiers in place it looks perfect. Exactly what I want to see:

[image]

However, when i apply this to the object, the topology is entirely ruined:

[image]

The underlying topology looks like this:

[image]

I have absolutely no practical experience using booleon operations so far in my Blender journey and I have absolutely no idea what to even attempt to fix this situation.

What should I start looking into first?

Comment: did you have any thickness modifiers or other etc that were not applied before the boolean? have you added the bevels for the circle edges after boolean to tighten?

Comment: No thickness modifiers as they were already cylinders. They had bevel edges before applying the boolean. But i've not added any bevels or edges after applying the boolean.

I'm a bit confused why it can apparently get it right before applying the bool and then get it so wrong when actually applying it

Comment: boolean on curved surfaces is often tedious to sort out, look up a tutorial on boolean on curves, that may help a lot. If not, then clarify what you have tried.

Comment: Avoid boolean operations, they will mess up your topology. The order of the modifiers matter Read  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/cutting-holes-with-boolean-modifier-makes-subdivision-surface-impossible/14041#14041

Comment: I'm just doing the Hard Surface Course from Gleb and it's absolutely brimming with Booleon operations. Seems to be a staple of that technique.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Judging from the rounded surfaces and the post-application deformations, I'd wager that you have an unapplied *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Once you've applied the boolean operation without applying the subsurf, the subsurf operation is now operating on the circular cutouts as well as the original mesh.

Consider not applying the boolean operation if possible. One of the biggest advantages of the boolean workflow is the procedural aspect of it. If not, backup the model and apply all other modifiers before applying the boolean.

Comment: You are correct. SubSurf -> Bool -> Bevel. would you apply the sub serf then the bool if you have too?

All I want to do is apply a material to the faces the bool will produce (when working). Is there a way to do this without applying the bool operation?

Comment: I would definitely prefer to not apply the bool if possible and I have backed it all up into backup layers.

Comment: Unfortunately no, not to my knowledge at least. I haven't heard of any method to assign different materials to surfaces you don't have direct access to

Comment: Good grief, such a simple solution. I can't believe that didn't occur to me. I just applied the SubiSerf, then the booleon and the mesh is perfect.