# Shade Smooth and holes

Tags: objects

I'm quite new to Blender and I have a problem when I'm using Shade Smooth. As soon as I am shade smoothing The object with the hole in it, there are some weird color changes around the hole. It doesn't change in the rendered image. [image]

The holes where made with the boolean modifier. Am I doing it the wrong way or is there a way to fix this?

Comment: In the mesh properties panel turn on "Auto Smooth" and adjust its value below 90°. https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.79/modeling/meshes/editing/normals.html#properties

Comment: bad topology will always come and haunt you. Avoid boleans..

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/14040/cutting-holes-with-boolean-modifier-makes-subdivision-surface-impossible

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Avoid boolean to create holes in a mesh. It will always create really bad topology and then when you apply subdivision and smooth shade, everything is going to fail.