# Creating a truck exhaust mesh

Tags: modeling, modifiers

I am trying to create an truck exhaust mesh with blender.

[image: Truck Exhaust]

Currently I am using a smaller size cylinder to cut inside and then using some other cylinders to cut every hole with boolean modifier.

[image: Cutting]
[image: Finished product]

**Problem**

As you see, the original mesh has many holes and cutting every single one of them with this method will take forever and if suddenly I decide to change the amount of holes in perimeter or exhaust diameter , I have to restart.

**Question**

Is there  any easier way to do this?

Comment: did you try a texture with transparent/glossy mixed material or it should be a real mesh ?

Comment: if I use a texture, will I see the mesh shadow on exhaust?

Comment: yes shadows of a real mesh (light will pass through transparent holes )

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-

Answer (score 15, accepted):

For creating a real mesh you can use the array and boolean modifiers as follows :

- create a cylinder 'C1' and put in the right position
- add an empty 'E1' rotate it 36°
- add an array modifier to C1 and use E1 as offset object, with a count of 5
- add a second empty 'E2' and rotate it 18°
- add array modifier to 'C1' and use 'E2' as offset object,with a count of 10 or more
- create a cylinder 'C2' and put in the right size and pose
- remove the top and bottom faces of 'C2'
- add a boolean modifier with target set to 'C1' and type to 'Difference'
- parent 'C2','E1' and 'E2' to 'C1' and hide them (so you don't need to apply the modifier until you are satisfied with the results)

[image]

***Note :*** i have add Bevel modifier to 'C1' and subsurf and solidify to 
'C2'  to get the previous result

---

To avoid having a dense mesh and dealing with the boolean modifier you can use a texture and transparent material to achieve the same results :

- use the following node setup for the material (you can replace the defuse with more complex shaders )
- use Follow active quad to unwrap the cylinder and map it correctly on the texture
- if the texture has an alpha channel use it instead of the RGB_BW converter in the material nodes

[image]

The result render :

[image]

Comment: I guess texture effect is much better solution, if I want to cut 236 holes in a cylinder, I will have over 10K faces on a single object. If I could I would accept your answer twice for explaining both ways.

Comment: thanks , you are right the texture is better since you have no simulations ( smoke ) in there

Answer (score 13):

Add a ***Bezier Circle*** and a part of the truck exhaust profile mesh. They both should have the same origin point.
[image]

Add the ***Array Modifier***, increase the  *Count* number, and check the *Merge* and *First Last* boxes.
[image]

Add the *Curve* and *Subsurf* modifiers.
[image]

Scale the profile a bit to close the cylinder.
[image]

When it's closed, you may scale the holes size as you like.
[image]

Select the edges of the holes and mark them as sharp <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd>-->Mark Sharp. It will be usefull in the next stage.
[image]

Apply the *Array* and *Curve* modifiers. Merge the vertices of the cylinder's closing edges (select the first, then last vertex and press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>M</kbd>-->At Last).
[image]

Now add the *Array Modifier* and increase the *Count* number to make the cylinder longer. Apply it, then, being in *Edit Mode*, remove doubles (hit <kbd>W</kbd>-->Remove Doubles).
[image]

Add *Solidify* (increase the *Thickness* value) and *Edge Split* modifiers.
[image]