# Is there an easy way to add a hole into an object?

Tags: modeling, topology

If I wanted to add a hole into an object e.g. Create a tube

Is there an easy way to do that?

I haven't seen anything regarding negative space so far in Blender, and it would be really helpful for my project

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you clarify what type of hole you are talking about. If it is something like the mouth of a cave, then you would have enough faces going in, until you could not see the end from the out side.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Examples

- In edit mode you can switch to face select mode (control tab).  Select faces and delete.  You may need to  created additional faces to delete.
- Extrude or inset and remove faces
- Use any mesh primitive with multiple faces and delete a face.
- Add more faces (loop cut and slide) and delete a face to create hole.
- Use a Boolean modifier with operation Delete to create additional geometry suitable to the final step to delete faces.
  In the image below we see from left to right

  - a plane
  - a plane with sphere placed to intersect the plane
  - goal mesh achieved with hole cut from Boolean modifier with [apply] clicked and user editing to delete extra vertices
  - plane selected with Boolean modifier present
  - plane with extra geometry created by Boolean modifier with [apply] clicked. Extra geometry will be deleted. N-gons may be present.

[image]

- If rectangular outside with circular hole is desired use a torus or sphere or cylinder and use a shrink wrap to a rectangular outside.  Below is an example of a torus with 3 vertex cross section.

[image]

- The geometry created above may be more suited to some situations rather than a triangulated n-gon.

Comment: But if I wanted to do that to a 3D shape, surely there would be no "inside walls" to the hole?

Comment: Boolean operates more on volumes.  The extra faces can be deleted.  One could say I really should have subtracted a sphere from a cube and then remove extra faces.  I was prioritizing quick response over other concepts.   I worked with what Blender has in front of me.  If your provide additional requirements in your question we can try to address them.