# Cylinder cutouts

Tags: modeling, modifiers

How can I make such cutouts in the cylinder in blender? Boolean operations? Or there is an easier way to do this?

Thank you!

[image: Cylinder cutouts]

Comment: The image has very low quality, maybe try to upload a better one if possible. Search for bool tool, you can make a cylinder and use it to cut out those "stripes"

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I change my answer because the first one was a bit tedious, beginning with knife, digging a hole then making a circle with the extrusion is much faster:

- Create a cylinder, mirror it, cut an oblique edge with the knife, bevel it several times, cut a hole.

[image]

- Extrude, the hole, make it a circle with <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd>, use *LoopTools > Space* if you need the circle vertices to be regularly spaced.

[image]

- Cut the top part, keep only a half circle, extrude the left and right edge and join the vertices to circle's vertices.

[image]

- Extrude down, fill the bottom of the extrusion. Give a *Subdivision Surface* modifier to your object. Add extra edge loops to sharp the edges.

[image]

Comment: Nicely done @moonboots!