# How can I model a spread cylinder type of shape?

Tags: modeling

I want to model this kind of spread cylinder type of shape and after multiple tries I can't figure out how.

[image: Better view of the cylinder]

[image: The cylinder thing]

I've tried using a primitive cylinder and then to spread its edges but that just resulted in a glitched cylinder, then I tried making my own cylinder from a primitive cube and spread the edges again and it just resulted in a glitched edge for the cube. How can I do this?

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/118549/cylinder-cutouts/118563#118563

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The aim is to construct edge loops along the curve.

[image]

A way to do it:

Start with an open cylinder, cut it in half and mirror it. Then extrude the bottom half part.

[image]

Add a circle (or the curve shape you want) with a high resolution. Then manually snap the top part of the cylinder so that it fits the curve.

[image]

Add two vertical knife cuts: one on the right to delimitate horizontal and vertical sections, the second on its left to give more precision to the curvature. For this last one adjust its top vertex (or vertice as some say) to the curve.

[image]

Extrude all the edge except the top 3 vertices, horizontaly to the cylinder center.

[image]

Add 3 loop cuts and fill the open faces, so that the first loop is now done.

[image]

Add two loop cuts to the exterior part, like so:

[image]

Use <kbd>X</kbd> *'dissolve egdes'* and *'dissolve vertices'* and also knife cuts <kbd>K</kbd> to adjust the geometry.
On left here an intermediate step, final step on the right.

[image]

Adjust vertices positions mainly using <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to slide along edges.

Add a subdivision surface.

[image]

The blend file includes this construction step by step:

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much! This was very helpful, you blew my mind.