# How to cut a hole in a curved surface and maintain good topology?

Tags: modeling, topology

**Blend file:** [image]

I am trying to add two holes to my shape (these holes will then connect to a truncated torus, forming the handle of a mug).

I was following this technique: https://youtu.be/Ci1jBOm_5NY?si=DxREsY7u4V1NFm87&t=183

**The issue:** my shape has a bit more curvature than the one in the example video, so either

1. The "cutter" has enough geometry to conform to the mug, but cleaning up the topology seems difficult because there are significantly more vertices/edges in the cutter than in the mug shape.
   [image]
2. The "cutter" has roughly the same "geometry density" (not sure what the appropriate terminology is) as the mug, but it is not enough to conform to all of the folds on the mug, so filling in the geometry would create the wrong shape. The side view shows how the shrinkwrapped mesh does not have enough geometry to fold correctly.
   [image]
   [image]

Comment: Does this help
https://youtu.be/bfdI_-ymkas?feature=shared

Comment: @RickT hmmm it is not working that well for me. When turning a set of faces into a circle, they all become co-planar, losing the curvature.

Comment: You may want to first subdivide your object a couple of times to give it more geometry to work with.

Comment: There's also [this](https://youtu.be/JvJ_Hoj82us?list=RDCMUCp7EwodJcppc6GqiRcnCpOw) video from Blender Secrets which discusses the techniques in more detail.

Comment: Related https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-