Solving smooth shading artefacts as a result of a circle on a non flat surface
I am trying to create circles on the edge between two faces that change directions. How can I do this better?

This is how I made the circles:

PS: This is a barrel of a gun. I want the model to be a game ready asset.

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-

Create your 16 vertex cylinder, add 3 vertical edges, select the vertex at the center, bevel it:

Tweak the parameters of the Operator Box to get a circle:

Extrude inwards, add this topology:

Bevel the edges:

Result with a Subdivision Surface modifier (I add to use Shrinkwrap onto a cylinder to correct a bit the surface around the hole):


Thank you! I did that, and it's better, but in shade smooth I can see a little bit of shading artefacts still.

could you please share your object? https://blend-exchange.com/

https://blend-exchange.com/b/mvegz4o1
PS: I think I resolved almost all the issues with shading and I don't want to use subdivision surface.

Well, if you don't want to use Subdivision Surface it's going to be hard to have a good shading, adding a Normal > Weighted Normal modifier will improve a bit

My intent with the model is to sculpt it and then apply the baked normal map to the low poly version.
You think this state of the model is ok for that?

then maybe edit your question and explain the whole project?

I did that. Thanks for the help, I learned something today :)

It's not clear what you are trying to bake from what

For now I just wanted to create circles in the edge of a cylinder with a clean topology. I learned that from you (great!). But also I want a clean smooth shading as a result of the operation.

Yes but it's currently too low poly to get a nice shading, you need to increase the amount of faces, maybe use a 24 or 32 vertex cylinder instead of 16, also at the end use the  Weighted Normal modifier

ok, thanks for the info! I will close this post.
