# Getting missing holes when cutting holes into a cylinder

Tags: modeling, modifiers

[image]

I'm trying to cut a bunch of holes (created using two Array Modifiers and an empty) into a cylinder using a boolean modifier. It looks legit in the wireframe. However, when I turn on the shading mode, I get this instead:

[image]

Some of the holes are clearly missing. I'm not sure what's going on.

Comment: Did you apply Array Modifiers?

Comment: Didn’t think I had to. What’s funny is that there are two rows of holes, though some holes are missing in either row.

Comment: Yeah that don't make sense, I think every first modifier act as applied! Not sure but may be.

Comment: Also it may be possible because its an Array of Array, that may be to far to be recognized by boolean before applying them!

Comment: Working for me in 279, and 280, built on 2019-02-08, without applying any modifiers... possibly share your file?

Comment: Yeah! Robin may be right, try sharing your blend file so we can further investigate!

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/79659/19307