# Is there any way to model these shapes while keeping the topology clean and not create shading issues?

Tags: modeling, mesh

[image]
First one is the wing and body of an aircraft intersecting at a very small angle. Second is a cockpit separated from incompatible mesh topology. The third one is piercing multiple holes through an n gon. I have yet to find decent solutions to any of them.

Comment: Hello :). If you want specific answers, please ask specific questions [How to Ask](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-ask). And please keep it one question per post :).

Comment: Related: [Regularly spaced holes in a cylinder](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/79650/78972)