# How to flatten a cylinder wall, then cut holes

Tags: mesh

I have a cylinder wall that needs an array of holes cut out into it.  If I use shrinkwrap the holes on the far ends are too distorted.  I would like to flatten the wall, then add cut holes.

[image: curve needs flattening]

[image: Being able to cut holes in UV unwrap would be perfect!]

Comment: if you plan to use a Boolean modifier afterwards it may give bad geometry, maybe you should rethink the way you do it, first create a segment, cut the window with a clean topology, array the segment, bend with the Simple Deform modifier...

Comment: This sounds like the [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), this issue has been solved many times before, see links below

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/226729/torus-pipe-joint-3d-printing https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/51233/perforated-plate/ https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/65395/repetitive-carving-holes-around-sphere https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/58811/grid-similar-to-a-manhole-cover https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/30996/is-there-an-easy-way-to-

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79650/regularly-spaced-holes-in-a-cylinder/

Comment: The real issue is how to flatten a cylinder wall to work on it.  The links above don't address this issue.  I need this flat so it can be cut and rolled manually...

Comment: Again, why don't you begin with a flat mesh, array, bend with the Simple Deform modifier?

Comment: It streches the oval holes on the ends of the array

Comment: @MarrMadden You have tried it with a flat mesh, _Array_ and _Simple Deform_ modifier? Then show us this approach and where you are stuck there so we might help, because done correctly it does not stretch the holes:  [flat mesh with array + bend](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGVOC.jpg)

Comment: Gordon, this worked! Thank you. Also helps when you accept all transformations... How do I mark your comment as the answer?

Comment: Hello, Marr, Glad @GordonBrinkmann has done it for you! Hoping he takes no offence, I think it's fair to close this one out, without building the comment into a fully-fledged answer that can be accepted, because many similar examples already exist in the archive. Nothing personal.. it's just that the problem has already been covered adequately on BSE.  If he objects, he can vote to re-open.