# Please help me fix geometry

Tags: modeling

I got this mesh,which was exported out of some engineering program like solidworks for example with STL FORMAT.
Please help me understand how to fix this. Is there a way to fix such crazy ugly triangles?

I will link blend file with mesh:
https://yadi.sk/d/GQ7gB_vdDy6jyw

[image]

Comment: Hello :). This mesh looks well suited for Limited Dissolve operator in *Mesh > Delete > Limited Dissolve*

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63196/how-to-make-this-cylinder-model-with-holes https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/79650/regularly-spaced-holes-in-a-cylinder