# how to retopologize a cylinder Boolean properly

Tags: modeling, modifiers, retopology

I applied a circle shaped Boolean to a cylinder and now have artifacts, I am trying to retopologize it but am not sure how to do it, I have attached the methods I have tried, does anyone know a better way to do it?

[image]
[image]

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/28103/creating-a-truck-exhaust-mesh https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to maintain an all quad mesh, then you could lower your number of vertices on your cutter object
Then it would look like this

[image]

Since we have an all quad mesh, with the help of subdivision surface modifier, we could make it look like this

[image]

If you're **not** aiming for an all quad mesh, you could watch this tutorial from Josh Gambrell to maintain perfect shading while having ngons in your mesh
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=W8FDlPcUCME&t=335s