# Best way to make smooth UV sphere with hole through it

Tags: modeling, workflow, subdivision-surface

keep in mind that I am a blender beginner. How would I go about making this sphere hole smoother.
After applying subdivision I get a distorted ring. My goal is to make this circle as smooth as possible. I tried adding loop cuts to smooth it out, but it just still inst what I want it to be.
[image: UV sphere with a hole in it, looking really bad with subdivision surface modifier]

Comment: It seems you used a boolean modifier. Try to use a subsurf to the figures first and than apply boolean.

Comment: Make a loop surrounding the hole and get rid of Ngons / long tiny faces and stuff. They all produce bad result with Subsurf.

Comment: no good way to fix that ---mess--- mesh. A low poly UV sphere booleaned is not going to have good topology, at all. You really have to restart, modeling one from a cylinder, or torus.

Comment: You can try this. https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5856/cutting-a-circular-hole-in-a-hollow-cylinder-without-distorting-the-cylinder/5859#5859

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can think of three ways to make this shape, *not* using a boolean.
Using a UV sphere (this is the best way), scaling a torus, or modeling it from a cylinder.
I'm not going to show the cylinder, because the other two methods are better, and after seeing them you will already know all the techniques used to model it off of the cylinder.

#### I'll start with the UV sphere.

With a default UV sphere, <kbd>Tab</kbd> into edit mode. Select both the top and bottom vertices at the polls of the sphere. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>NumPad +</kbd> once, to enlarge the selection. Delete those selected vertices <kbd>X</kbd> > *Vertices*.
Select the inner edge loop on both the top and bottom, <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>RMB</kbd> to select an edge loop.
[image: correct selection on the UV sphere]
Now with that selected bridge the edge loops. <kbd>W</kbd> > *Bridge Edge Loops*.
Add one to the *Number of Cuts* while the bridge edge loops operator is still active.

Select the only edge loop in the middle of the new bridged part, and press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd> to bevel it. Move the edges until they are closer to the corner (this will make the subdivision surface look better).

A gif of all that:
[image: animated gif showing how to cut a hole in a UV sphere]

---

#### Scaling a Torus

Add a torus, and change the *Minor Radius* so that the "hole" is smaller.
Now what I like to do is add a sphere in the same spot as the torus, it will only act as a guide.
[image: torus and guide sphere]
With the whole torus selected, scale it to make it fatter (with the default rotation that would be along the Z axis).
Now select the bottom and top edge loops, and scale them along the Z until they about line up with the sphere guide in the background, this makes it look more round and less torus like.
Do the same for the first pare of edge loops on the inside of the "hole". At this point it looks like a sphere with a hole, not a torus.

Only thing left to do is straighten the inside of the hole. I did this by dissolving the middle three edge loops into one, then just scaling it to the same size as the top and bottom.

Again an nice gif of the above process:
[image: animated gif showing how to scale a torus into a sphere with a hole in it]