# Making a clean cut out of a sphere

Tags: edges, topology

I want to cut a specific (but not very complicated) shape out of a sphere like so:

[image]

But the result is always bad looking due to tris and close proximity vertices.  The best I can get is using Edge Split:

[image]

Is there a way to get a clean result?  I've looked elsewhere and saw some people mention that this needs some manual work - how do I put in the manual work to make it look better?  I don't mind since my shapes are generally quite simple.

Comment: You will need to use exactly same method: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/96342/how-to-save-curve-shape-of-cylinder-with-such-deform/96344#96344 Don't use boolean, just manually place vertices in any shape you want.

Comment: Check this out: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=salpctjEdAA

Comment: Relared https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/66942/how-would-you-model-a-sphere-with-a-shell-like-object

Comment: Also related: [Best way to make smooth UV sphere with hole through it](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/95240/2217)