# Need help modeling a circle inset on a slanted surface

Tags: modeling

[image]

I'm trying to model this little section of this scope, mainly the slanted hole that the bolt sits into. I've tried to boolean it and that just makes a mess of everything. Is a boolean the best option and I'm just not doing it right or is there a cleaner way of modeling this?

Comment: Please see this answer https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/123843/how-to-make-a-circular-cut/123844#123844

Comment: What sort of mess? please post screenshots. I tried a quick Cube mesh scaled and rotated to 45 degrees and then used the Boolean modifier with a Cylinder and it created OK geometry. I got even better results by adding a SubDiv Modifier set to Simple to the Cube first.

Comment: Sorry this is what I mean by a mess: https://imgur.com/QqkB4Vn i'm not sure if attempting to clean that up is a good workflow or if i'm doing the boolean process correctly or not.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it with a *Boolean* modifier, please tell me if you don't understand one of the steps:

[image]

Comment: When going from step 4 to step 5, did you use a solidify modifier?

Comment: I just extruded